# (short) Proof explanation of indexed unity - why does such n exists

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification, alternative-proof

this proof and specifically the first line is throwing me off. How can we assume such a value n_x exists? How would one argue for this? (or does this method not work?)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to Archimedean Principle for every $0<\epsilon <1$ there exist an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$. So $1-\frac{1}{n}>1-\epsilon $.  But $1-\epsilon $ is arbitrary, Therefore for every $0<x<1$, there is $n_x\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1-\frac{1}{n_x}>x $

Comment: This makes sense. I got the hint to use the number 1/(1-x) but this should be sufficient.